# How to transform SRID 2263 polygon to SRID 4326?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I parsed shapefile with Python and found SRID 2263 format shape. I want to put it into PostgreSQL database as a SRID 4326 polygon. Is it possible?

st_transform responds with error [-2020]

Comment: That appears to be a projection for Long Island? What do you get when you run select * from spatial_ref_sys where srid=2263; If nothing, then this is your problem and the solution depends on what version of Postgis you are using.

Comment: Even this gives me nothing `SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name='spatial_ref_sys'`.

I am not the admin of the DB, so I think I will stick to Python libraries which will do the job.

Thank you!

Comment: OK. If you change your mind, it's an easy fix. Create extension postgis in newer versions of Postgres/Postgis and running a sql script in older versions. http://postgis.net/install/